# Why when i change the Camera in the Inspector Culling Mask to Nothing when i'm running the game it return automatic to Everything?

Tags: unity, c#

I don't have a Main Camera.
The only Camera i have for now is on the FirstPersonCharacter as component.

[image: SB1]

Either changing the Culling Mask by editor in the Inspector or by script from Everything to Nothing when running the game it return to Everything and never stay on Nothing.

The only active script that is attached to the FirstPersonCharacter is: Antialiasing: Not my script. But not sure if this what make it change back all the time the Culling Mask to Everything.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects
{
    public enum AAMode
    {
        FXAA2 = 0,
        FXAA3Console = 1,
        FXAA1PresetA = 2,
        FXAA1PresetB = 3,
        NFAA = 4,
        SSAA = 5,
        DLAA = 6,
    }

    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    [RequireComponent(typeof (Camera))]
    [AddComponentMenu("Image Effects/Other/Antialiasing")]
    public class Antialiasing : PostEffectsBase
    {
        public AAMode mode = AAMode.FXAA3Console;

        public bool showGeneratedNormals = false;
        public float offsetScale = 0.2f;
        public float blurRadius = 18.0f;

        public float edgeThresholdMin = 0.05f;
        public float edgeThreshold = 0.2f;
        public float edgeSharpness = 4.0f;

        public bool dlaaSharp = false;

        public Shader ssaaShader;
        private Material ssaa;
        public Shader dlaaShader;
        private Material dlaa;
        public Shader nfaaShader;
        private Material nfaa;
        public Shader shaderFXAAPreset2;
        private Material materialFXAAPreset2;
        public Shader shaderFXAAPreset3;
        private Material materialFXAAPreset3;
        public Shader shaderFXAAII;
        private Material materialFXAAII;
        public Shader shaderFXAAIII;
        private Material materialFXAAIII;


        public Material CurrentAAMaterial()
        {
            Material returnValue = null;

            switch (mode)
            {
                case AAMode.FXAA3Console:
                    returnValue = materialFXAAIII;
                    break;
                case AAMode.FXAA2:
                    returnValue = materialFXAAII;
                    break;
                case AAMode.FXAA1PresetA:
                    returnValue = materialFXAAPreset2;
                    break;
                case AAMode.FXAA1PresetB:
                    returnValue = materialFXAAPreset3;
                    break;
                case AAMode.NFAA:
                    returnValue = nfaa;
                    break;
                case AAMode.SSAA:
                    returnValue = ssaa;
                    break;
                case AAMode.DLAA:
                    returnValue = dlaa;
                    break;
                default:
                    returnValue = null;
                    break;
            }

            return returnValue;
        }


        public override bool CheckResources()
        {
            CheckSupport(false);

            materialFXAAPreset2 = CreateMaterial(shaderFXAAPreset2, materialFXAAPreset2);
            materialFXAAPreset3 = CreateMaterial(shaderFXAAPreset3, materialFXAAPreset3);
            materialFXAAII = CreateMaterial(shaderFXAAII, materialFXAAII);
            materialFXAAIII = CreateMaterial(shaderFXAAIII, materialFXAAIII);
            nfaa = CreateMaterial(nfaaShader, nfaa);
            ssaa = CreateMaterial(ssaaShader, ssaa);
            dlaa = CreateMaterial(dlaaShader, dlaa);

            if (!ssaaShader.isSupported)
            {
                NotSupported();
                ReportAutoDisable();
            }

            return isSupported;
        }


        public void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
        {
            if (CheckResources() == false)
            {
                Graphics.Blit(source, destination);
                return;
            }

            // ----------------------------------------------------------------
            // FXAA antialiasing modes

            if (mode == AAMode.FXAA3Console && (materialFXAAIII != null))
            {
                materialFXAAIII.SetFloat("_EdgeThresholdMin", edgeThresholdMin);
                materialFXAAIII.SetFloat("_EdgeThreshold", edgeThreshold);
                materialFXAAIII.SetFloat("_EdgeSharpness", edgeSharpness);

                Graphics.Blit(source, destination, materialFXAAIII);
            }
            else if (mode == AAMode.FXAA1PresetB && (materialFXAAPreset3 != null))
            {
                Graphics.Blit(source, destination, materialFXAAPreset3);
            }
            else if (mode == AAMode.FXAA1PresetA && materialFXAAPreset2 != null)
            {
                source.anisoLevel = 4;
                Graphics.Blit(source, destination, materialFXAAPreset2);
                source.anisoLevel = 0;
            }
            else if (mode == AAMode.FXAA2 && materialFXAAII != null)
            {
                Graphics.Blit(source, destination, materialFXAAII);
            }
            else if (mode == AAMode.SSAA && ssaa != null)
            {
                // ----------------------------------------------------------------
                // SSAA antialiasing
                Graphics.Blit(source, destination, ssaa);
            }
            else if (mode == AAMode.DLAA && dlaa != null)
            {
                // ----------------------------------------------------------------
                // DLAA antialiasing

                source.anisoLevel = 0;
                RenderTexture interim = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(source.width, source.height);
                Graphics.Blit(source, interim, dlaa, 0);
                Graphics.Blit(interim, destination, dlaa, dlaaSharp ? 2 : 1);
                RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(interim);
            }
            else if (mode == AAMode.NFAA && nfaa != null)
            {
                // ----------------------------------------------------------------
                // nfaa antialiasing

                source.anisoLevel = 0;

                nfaa.SetFloat("_OffsetScale", offsetScale);
                nfaa.SetFloat("_BlurRadius", blurRadius);

                Graphics.Blit(source, destination, nfaa, showGeneratedNormals ? 1 : 0);
            }
            else
            {
                // none of the AA is supported, fallback to a simple blit
                Graphics.Blit(source, destination);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting a camera to render nothing is an unusual choice. Usually we'd do this by disabling the camera, rather than setting a culling mask of nothing. If you can describe your end goal, we might be able to suggest other ways of achieving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add image effects to the camera if your culling mask is set to nothing. If the culling mask is not at least set to something, the Unity Engine sets it to everything by default.